# Initialize 1 dimensional array of TreeVew Nodes

Tags: arrays, vb.net, treeview

I am using the TreeView Find method to find a node in a TreeView control. If the node is not found I create it. Later in the procedure I pass the new node to another procedure. The Find method returns a 1 dimensional array of nodes. When I create the node I also need to create it as a 1 dimensional array so I can pass the same type of object to the new procedure. That is where I'm stuck.

I can't use the New keyword when creating the node array and I'm not sure how to initialize it. When I try to access any of its properties it throws an exception because it is still Nothing. I got around this by only passing the first element of the array returned by the Find method, but this is still bugging me. I'm missing something obvious and I don't know what it is.

```
Dim ThisClaim() As TreeView.Node
ThisClaim(0).Text = "New node text"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the size of the array when you create it. Then you need to instantiate the `TreeNode` object that you add.

```
Dim ThisClaim(0) As TreeView.Node  'An array of 1 TreeNode (upper bound = 0)
ThisClaim(0) = New TreeNode("New node text")  'Instantiate a TreeNode and put it in ThisClaim(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is Monday, because I could have sworn I did that. I also tried ThisClaim.SetValue(New TreeView.Node("New node text"), 0).

Anyway...thanks.

Greg

Comment: this is not an answer - it should be a comment to the answer